# Pass Variable from $.ajax() to ASMX Web Service

Tags: jquery, .net, web-services

Can someone show me how to pass a variable from a $.ajax() call to an ASMX Web Service?

Web Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Psyience
{
    public int ID;
    public string Choice;
    public string First;
    public string Last;
    public string Email;
}
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptType(typeof(Psyience))]
public class CRUD : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public Psyience[] Anchor()
    {
        List<Psyience> items = new List<Psyience>();
        string constr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select Choice from tbl_Psyience WHERE Choice = 'Anchor'";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Psyience item = new Psyience();
                item.Choice = dr["Choice"].ToString();
                items.Add(item);
            }
            con.Close();
            return items.ToArray();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "Services/CRUD.asmx/Anchor",
        data: "{ }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var result = response.d;
            var myRecord = "";
            $.each(result, function (index, res) {
                myRecord = res.Choice;
            $('#myDiv').append(myRecord);
            });

        },
        error: function (msg) {
            $('#myErr').html("Error while calling web service,,")
        }
    });
});
```

I'd like to pass a string value from the jQuery to my command text in my web service.

"select Choice from tbl_Psyience WHERE Choice = 'passVarToHere'"

Not sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that in the **data** attribute of your ajax Request

```
data: { 'Choice' : yourchoice },  // Yourchoice in string
```

And your WebMethod will take in a string argument

```
public Psyience[] Anchor(string Choice)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

and ofcourse, the 'choice' variable can take value from a textbox control like so:

```
var passvartoHere = $("#txtbox").val();
```

EDIT: my solution to be used in conjunction with the solution already posted above.